# how can I restrict admin user permissions per field in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Is it possible to restrict an admin user on a attribute field basis? For example I would like some users/user role to edit stock of a product and the short description however I don't want them to be able to change fields like the product name and sku.
Do you have any idea ?